# Magento 2.2.5 Product attribute "use in search" RESETTING after index:reindex

Tags: attributes, search, catalogsearch, magento-2.2.5

**UPDATE:: Today i discover that happen when the cron run index:reindex**

### **How can I fix?**

Today during configuring  manufacturer attributes I found a bug or however an anomaly on Magento 2.2.5
I, setting "use in search" on "Yes" in the product attribute, but after a search on the frontend (the website return true result only the first search, after not found nothing)
The product attribute get on "No" completely alone.

[image: Set yes]
[image: searching with correct results]
[image: update backend]

Comment: no one know how resolve?...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when I used Mirasvit_Search module.
Maybe it is related to your issue as well.
After I added a product attribute to Mirasvit's index the issue has gone away.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, its saves our time, we are facing the same issue from last week and our good luck that you replied on this and our problem solved, thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant! After struggling for months with this issue this was the solution for us. Thanks!